# Dates manipulation between Spreadsheet and Arrays

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a function to look over a list of days (a year school calendar), and, compare with a date from a user prompt and, until the date (all the days "lower" than the user date) set in the B column a string (in this case "Summer holidays", only *if* there's not another value in the B column corresponding to cell.

What I have: [image: this is the table as seen before action]

What I expect, if I set Sept 12th in the input: [image]

```
function setTrimesters() {
  var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("calendar2017");

  // Start of 1st trimester
  var input = ui.prompt("Set first day of trimester (DD/MM)");
  var value = input.getResponseText();

  var allStartEndTrimesters = [valorInici1rTri]

  // Get dataRange
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A1:B'+sheet.getLastRow());

  // Get dataRange values
  var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();

  for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {    
    if (data[i][0] < value) {
      if (data[i][1] == '') {
        data[i][1] = "Summer holidays";
      }
    }
  }
  dataRange.setValues(data);     
}
```

The script is working *only* with the *day* value of the date. Then, in October, from 1st to 11th the script assign too the value "Summer holidays".

I don't know how to get day *and* month values before comparing. I've tried to setNumberFormat to miliseconds, or days (similar to 42895 or so)... but there are some limitations with SpreadsheetApp and App Scripts working with dates.

Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you work with dates as *strings*, so they get compared in lexicographic order. With day being first, 4/9 precedes 5/7, which is not what you wanted. I suggest to

- Use `getValues` instead of `getDisplayValues`. It will retrieve JavaScript date object instead of a string. Then the comparison `<` works correctly, but you also need the beginning date to be a Date object: see below.
- Do not overwrite input data in column A. Separate input and output ranges.

Here is an example, with user-interface part removed:

```
function testSummer() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();    
  var userEnteredDate = "26/07";    // what you get from user
  var dateParts = userEnteredDate.split("/");
  var beginning = new Date();
  beginning.setMonth(dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]);  
  beginning.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);  // so it's 0 hour of the day entered, in the current year

  var inputData = sheet.getRange('A1:A'+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var outputRange = sheet.getRange('B1:B'+sheet.getLastRow());
  var outputData = outputRange.getValues(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
    if (inputData[i][0] < beginning && outputData[i][0] == "") {
      outputData[i][0] = "summer vacation";
    }
  }
  outputRange.setValues(outputData);  // not overwriting input
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I'm integrating your solution in my structure, if it's properly working I'll later post an answer to share. Thanks again!